# How to use a Route Parameter within a Vaadin page

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, spotify

I am creating a Spring application using Vaadin with the help of the Spotify API and a Java Wrapper for the API. I am trying to grab a Route Parameter from the RouteLink that navigates to the current page, and use that String parameter to help me display the information I need.

The page with the RouterLink has a for-loop that loops through a search result of various songs and then provides a link for each song with a different route parameter of the Spotify Track ID.

```
RouterLink songPageLink = new RouterLink("Song Details", songDescription.class, new RouteParameters("trackID", track.getId()));
```

This is the code for the page I am working on:

```
package trackour.trackour.views.songDescription;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Paragraph;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterObserver;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.auth.AnonymousAllowed;

import trackour.trackour.views.api.APIController;

@Route("songDescription/:trackID?")
@PageTitle("Description")
@AnonymousAllowed
@Component
public class songDescription extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private String trackID;

    public songDescription() {

        H1 songTitle = new H1("SONG NAME");
        H2 songArtist = new H2("SONG ARTIST");
        Image albumCover = new Image();

        Paragraph acousticnessDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph danceabilityDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph energyDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph instrumentalnessDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph keyDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph livenessDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph loudnessDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph modeDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph tempoDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph timeSignatureDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        Paragraph valenceDetail = new Paragraph("VALUE");
        
        add(albumCover, songTitle, songArtist, acousticnessDetail, danceabilityDetail, 
            energyDetail, instrumentalnessDetail, keyDetail, livenessDetail, loudnessDetail, 
            modeDetail, tempoDetail, timeSignatureDetail, valenceDetail);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        trackID = event.getRouteParameters().get("trackID").orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

The code works fine the way I have provided it, but once I try to use the `trackID` variable, I get different Spring Bean exceptions.

Here's an example of how I want to use the Route Parameter:

```
H1 songTitle = new H1(APIController.getTrackName(trackID));
```

Once I do that, I get given this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'songDescription' defined in file [C:\Users\gohar\OneDrive\SFU\CMPT276\trackour\target\classes\trackour\trackour\views\songDescription\songDescription.class]: Failed to instantiate [trackour.trackour.views.songDescription.songDescription]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1314) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at trackour.trackour.Application.main(Application.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [trackour.trackour.views.songDescription.songDescription]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "replacement" is null
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1014) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:997) ~[na:na]        
        at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2940) ~[na:na]
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.AbstractRequest$Builder.setPath(AbstractRequest.java:244) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.data.tracks.GetTrackRequest$Builder.build(GetTrackRequest.java:89) ~[spotify-web-api-java-8.0.0.jar:na]
        at trackour.trackour.views.api.APIController.getTrackName(APIController.java:300) ~[classes/:na]
        at trackour.trackour.views.songDescription.songDescription.<init>(songDescription.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]    
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:198) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the `trackID` in the constructor, but here it is not yet initialized.
You have to move/call the code using `trackID` into the beforeEnter method or to another routing life cycle event that happens after the `beforeEnter`, preferably `afterNavigation` for example when you need to access the backend and modify / populate UI with data.